# Short story or book in which a man turns into a giant and is climbed by another man

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, biology

Looking for a short story or book in which a man turns into a giant and is climbed by another man, who runs into interesting flora and fauna on the giant, and even resorts to eating a mite on the giant's face.

Comment: Welcome to the site. When did you read this story, and when do you think it might've been published?

Comment: There is a chapter in Gene Wolfe's *The Sword of the Lictor* where the protagonist climbs a mountain shaped like a man, but I don't think the other details fit.